# electron packaged into asar target windows , config json with api key setting, is safe?

Tags: json, security, electron, asar

If an app is packaged with asar and the electron app uses a settings json file that I created that includes api key info... is this is a terrible idea related to security? How hard is it for someone to view this json file in plain-text?

Answer (score 0):

> How hard is it for someone to view this json file in plain-text?

Asar is nothing more than a simple archive, pretty much anyone can extract and read file inside.

https://github.com/electron/asar#asar---electron-archive : 
`it works like tar that concatenates all files together without compression`

Comment: Yep. I will need to move some me of my stuff to remote server and make a call to it ... this way I can protect and safeguard the api key and not have it visible in the electron Asar